# Change Mousepointer and font color by entering a cell in Qtableview

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtableview

I tried something out with QTableview and want that the mousepointer changed to "hand" and font color changed to blue if I enter a specific cell in QTableview. Is that possible? So the cell should be use like a button without being a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provide you a demo, maybe you want this.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

import numpy as np

class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._data = np.random.randint(0, 255, (5, 10))
        self._color = dict()

    def rowCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = ...) :
        if index.isValid() and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(self._data[index.row(), index.column()])

        if index.isValid() and role == Qt.ForegroundRole:
            if f"{index.row(),index.column()}" in self._color:
                return self._color[f"{index.row(),index.column()}"]

    def setData(self, index: QModelIndex, value, role: int = ...) -> bool:
        if index.isValid() and role == Qt.ForegroundRole:
            self._color = dict()
            self._color[f"{index.row(),index.column()}"] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(self.index(0,0), self.index(self.rowCount()-1, self.columnCount() -1))
            return True
        return super().setData(index, value, role)


class View(QTableView):
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        index = self.indexAt(e.pos())
        if index.isValid():
            self.model().setData(index, QBrush(Qt.blue), Qt.ForegroundRole)
            self.setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)
        else:
            self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        return super().mouseMoveEvent(e)


app = QApplication([])
v = View()
v.setMouseTracking(True)
v.setModel(Model())
v.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Exactly what i need. If i add mousePressEvent or mouseReleaseEvent i can make the cell clickable right? just one additional question: i built my UI with the Qt-designer. How can i add the eventfunctions in the tableView i create with the designer and not by writing it by myself? Can i just subclass the views too?

Comment: @陈-杰 What's the point of using a dictionary, if you always create a new one?

Comment: @Robert by default, all "cells" are already clickable, so you don't need to override anything. Maybe you were referring to the item selection? About the Designer question, do some research on "widget promotion"

Comment: @musicamante  create dict is to record position color info, and remove dict is to clear previous color info when  new  color need to set.

Comment: @陈-杰 then it's actually pointless to use a dict, especially considering that you're using a *string* as its key and there will always be *one* key. While I don't agree with your approach, I can understand and accept its behavior, but using a dict for that is completely unnecessary if used like that: it's like moving a crane to catch a fly. You could've just used a default attribute set to `None` and then verify if the attribute matches the index row/column combination (using a string, or, better, a tuple): `if self._color == (index.row(), index.column())`: ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Such "visual" hints should never modify the underlying model, and should always be managed by the *item delegate* instead.

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class ItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.highlightedCells = []

    def setHighlightedCells(self, cells):
        self.highlightedCells.clear()
        for row, column in cells:
            self.highlightedCells.append((row, column))

    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        if not (index.row(), index.column()) in self.highlightedCells:
            return
        if option.state & QStyle.State_MouseOver:
            option.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, Qt.blue)

    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):
        if event.type() == event.MouseMove:
            if (index.row(), index.column()) in self.highlightedCells:
                option.widget.viewport().setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)
            else:
                option.widget.viewport().unsetCursor()
        return super().editorEvent(event, model, option, index)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    table = QTableWidget(5, 5)
    for r in range(5):
        for c in range(5):
            table.setItem(r, c, 
                QTableWidgetItem('{} {}'.format(r + 1, c + 1)))

    # required for updates on mouse movements (especially the cursor)
    table.setMouseTracking(True)
    delegate = ItemDelegate(table)
    table.setItemDelegate(delegate)
    # the following is for the fourth column of the first 3 rows
    delegate.setHighlightedCells([(0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3)])

    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it. I'm new in the modelview and in the past I did such thinks with tablewidget but the model seems more flexible. On the other side I think the modelview is more complicated so I try to understand the technics at the first. I think I'm on a good way and I have first models in my layout, but I still don't really understand the delegate. But I will do my best. Thank you

Comment: QTableWidget *is* a model/view, it's just a higher level view that already implements the model on its own, but while it's fine for more "static" and basic data, it has many limitations most importantly on the "model side". The delegate is what a view uses to *display* the data and allows *user interaction* with the model. The name is exactly what it does: the view *delegates* to an "item delegate" the job of showing data and provide means to access or edit it for the user. I suggest you to take your time and [read the docs](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes).